# How to modify multi documents' field in Mongodb? The new value is the extension of the original one

Tags: mongodb

I have mongodb documents:

```
{
    "_id" : 1,
    "site": "www.a.com"
}

{
    "_id" : 1,
    "site": "www.b.com"
}
```

I want to modify them to:

```
{
    "_id" : 1,
    "site": "http://www.a.com"
}

{
    "_id" : 1,
    "site": "http://www.b.com"
}
```

I read the doc on mongodb, but don't how to add `http://` instead of setting new value.

```
db.test.update(
   { _id: 1 },
   { $set: { site: ? } },
   { multi: true }
)
```

Comment: same {_id : 1} in your collection? It is not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Disposer pointed out, it's not possible to have multiple documents in a collection with the same `_id`.  Assuming that was a typo, you can make use of the cursor function [`forEach()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.forEach/) in the **mongo shell** to achieve what you want:

```js
db.foo.find().forEach( function(myDoc) { 
  db.foo.update({"_id": myDoc._id}, {$set: {"site": "http:\\" + myDoc.site}}); 
})
```